# combining two identical tables( actually table fields) into one 

Tags: mysql, oracle

this is actually [a followup from a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3873398/copying-data-from-one-database-field-to-another-database-field) but it contains different information , so I decided to start a new topic.
Summary :

I have 2 tables  one  TMP_TABLE  and a BKP_TABLE.  Both have the same fieldstructure and identical datatypes for the fields( with almost identical data).

let's say TMP_TABLE is constructed like this

```
TMP_TABLE

NAME      PREFIX      PARAMETERS 
data      data        data
data      data        data
data      data        data
```

and BKP_TABLE looks like this

```
BKP_TABLE

NAME      PREFIX      PARAMETERS 
data1      data1        data1
data1      data1        data1
data1      data1        data1
```

Is it possible to combine these two tables into one that looks like this

```
END_RESULTTABLE 

   
    NAME      PREFIX      PARAMETERS 
    data      data1        data1
    data      data1        data1
    data      data1        data1
```

As you can see I wish to drop one of the fields and replace it with another.
The sequence is pretty much the same so I don't have to worry about records being incorrect.

**A side question**

At the moment both TMP and BKP  contain the exact same data ( 113 records)
when I do this

```
SELECT * FROM TMP_TABLE 
UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM BKP_TABLE
```

I get 226.  Why does this happen. I thought that duplicate entries ( which I can clearly see) would not appear in my virtual table.

**EDIT:**

I would like to replace one field of TMP_data with BKP_table field ( example like name).

Comment: At the moment it is not at all clear what you want to do.  How about some (simple) realistic data rather than just the word "data" repeated everywhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your two tables have a key in common (e.g. name), you can do something like this:

```
create table end_resulttable as
select t.name, t.prefix, b.parameters
from   tmp_table t, bkp_table b
where  t.name = b.name;
```

Is that what you mean?

Comment: I too got that far, unfortunately it doesn't quite do what I want. Because now it multiplies my records so when I do this I get 113 * 113  records in my new end_resulttable. And what I want( if it's possible ) is actually just replace a field of data.  I'll make an edit to my post.

Comment: If you got 113*113 rows, i.e. a Cartesian product, that means you didn't specify a join condition ("where t.name = b.name" in my answer) - OR that the column you joined on isn't a key, and has the same value in all 113 rows!

Comment: Do your tables in fact have keys, or are you just hoping to "line up" row 1 of table A with row 1 of table B and so on?  If so, databases DON'T work like that.

Comment: Thank you!...  indeed I did not specify my pk so I got the cartesian product. top

Answer (score 3):

```
UNION ALL
```

will return **all** records from both selects (hence the **ALL**)

```
UNION
```

will remove duplicates

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  UNfortunately I tried union before I tried union all. And both give me the same result.

Comment: @jovany, yes, of course: `UNION` removes *duplicates*. If the rows are not completely identical then they are not duplicates.

Comment: aha of course, so for my eye they probably "look"  identical but content wise there is probably a slight difference.  Thank you.

Comment: Ok so I was missing my primary key, that was my problem. Thanks